# Separate UICollectionView dataSource and delegate not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I'm attempting to use a separate class for my `UICollectionView` DataSource and Delegate, but the methods are not being called.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

```
(Root VC)        -> (Current Screen) -> (Current Page)       -> (CollectionView in question)
UIViewController -> UIViewController -> UIPageViewController -> UICollectionView
```

This is the class for the `Current Screen` VC.

```
import UIKit

class FooController: UIViewController {
  // PageViewController
  let pageController = UIPageViewController(/*...*/)
  let pageOne = UIViewController()
  let pageTwo = UIViewController()

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    // Setup Stuff
    bootstrapPageOne()
  }

  func bootstrapPageOne() {
    // Do PageView Stuff
    bootstrapBars()
  }

  func bootstrapBars() {
    // Everything is set up when this function is called.

    let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cellSize : CGFloat = 60

    let collectionViewWidth = view.bounds.width - 20 * 2 //CGFloat(barsCount.count) * cellSize
    let collectionViewHeight = cellSize
    let collectionViewFrame : CGRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: view.bounds.height - (60 + view.layer.cornerRadius), width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)

    let barCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: collectionViewFrame, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
    let fooBarHandler = FooBarCollectionHandler()
    barCollectionView.delegate = fooBarHandler
    barCollectionView.dataSource = fooBarHandler
    barCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "barCellIdentifier")
    barCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    pageOne.view.addSubview(barCollectionView)
  }
}
```

This is the class for the CollectionView DataSource and Delegate

```
import UIKit

class FooBarCollectionHandler: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  let settings = SettingsHandler.sharedSettings

  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    debugPrint(#function)
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    debugPrint(#function)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("barCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    debugPrint(#function)
    return settings.bars.count // 5
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    debugPrint(#function)
    return CGSizeMake(40,40)
  }
}

// MARK: - Touch handling
extension FooBarCollectionHandler {
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    debugPrint(#function)
    debugPrint(indexPath.row)
  }
}
```

With the current configuration, none of the delegate/datasource methods are called. I can call `barCollectionView.numberOfSections()` or `barCollectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(_:)` and it will call and return, but they are not called automatically.

**NOTE: The `UICollectionView` renders fine, but the cells do not.**

Comment: (Where) do you call bootstrapBars() in your ViewController?

Comment: Sorry, it's done in a `boostrapPageOne()` method. I'l update the code to make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `foobarhandler` has a weak reference as Delegate. So when you leave the scope of `bootstrapBars`, it is released.

Store it locally to keep a reference :

```
var myDelegate : FooBarCollectionHandler?

func bootstrapBars() {
    //your stuff
    myDelegate = FooBarCollectionHandler()
    barCollectionView.delegate = myDelegate
    barCollectionView.dataSource = myDelegate

}
```

Comment: Beautiful, that worked for me! Do you have a reference to documentation that states that delegates are weak references?

Comment: Yes : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionView/delegate

FYI, all the delegate must be weak var, otherwise you will have retain cycles and then Memory leaks

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate the link. I'll keep the `weak` requirement in mind as well.